# the smallest value of $\alpha$

Tags: calculus

$f$ is a continuous function on the interval $[0,1] $ which satisfy:

1) $f(x) \leq \sqrt{5}$ for all $x \in [0,1] $

2) $f(x) \leq \frac{2}{x}$ for all $x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$

Then find the smallest real $\alpha$ such that the inequality $ \int^1_0  f(x) dx \leq \alpha$ holds for any such $f$.

Actually I'm relatively new to calculus, and hence to do not know how to proceed. I can do the most basic ones, but I haven't got any idea about this.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Okay. Got that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is find $\alpha = \int ^1 _0 \min \{\sqrt 5, \frac 2 x\} dx$. You do that by finding $x_1$ where $\frac 2 {x_1} = \sqrt 5$ and then finding $\int_0^{x_1} \sqrt 5 dx + \int _{x_1}^1 \frac x 2 dx$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you elucidate? I can't understand why did you do the steps you did.

Comment: Karolis found the point x1 where Sqrt(5) < 2/x goes to Sqrt(5)>2/x to be able to integrate over the smallest possible function.

Comment: @meredith, of all the functions satisfying your two inequalities, there is one for which $\int_0^1 f$ is the greatest. That function is $\min \{\sqrt 5, \frac 2 x\}$. Do you see why? Do you see how to integrate it?